# Symfony forms Length constraint overrides NotBlank constraint

Tags: forms, symfony, constraints

So in my form I have a field to insert password. On the field in the formbuilder I added 2 constraints; one for if the field is empty and one for if the password is too short.

```
new NotBlank([
    'message' => 'reset.password.error.enterpassword',
]),
new Length([
    'min' => 6,
    'minMessage' => 'reset.password.error.passwordtooshort',
    // max length allowed by Symfony for security reasons
    'max' => 4096,
]),
```

However, when I leave the password field empty, it will use the Length constraint (I kind of understand, as the password with length 0 is lower than 6), but shouldn't it use the NotBlank constraint since it's defined?

I also tried putting it after the Length constraint but it still didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The behaviour of the `Length` validator has changed in recent symfony versions.

Formerly it did **not** match empty inputs.

The option `allowEmptyString` controls wether empty strings are allowed.

It defaults to `false` while older symfony versions defaulted to `true`.

See the documentation [Length#allowemptystring](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Length.html#allowemptystring).

Set `allowEmptyString` to `true` to solve your issue:

```php
new Length([
    'allowEmptyString' => true,
    'min' => 6,
    'minMessage' => 'reset.password.error.passwordtooshort',
    // max length allowed by Symfony for security reasons
    'max' => 4096,
]),
new NotBlank([
    'message' => 'reset.password.error.enterpassword',
]),
```